# Activity has leaked window - ProgressDialog

Tags: android, memory-leaks, progressdialog

I have an OnSingleTapListener on my MapView object in the onCreate method in my Main Activity.

I am trying to create and show a Progress Dialog after tapping on the MapView, but I keep getting error on this line:

```
// Tap on the map and show popups for selected features.
        mapView.setOnSingleTapListener(new OnSingleTapListener() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            public void onSingleTap(float x, float y) {
                if (mapView.isLoaded()) {
                    // Instantiate a PopupContainer
                    popupContainer = new PopupContainer(mapView);
                    int id = popupContainer.hashCode();
                    if (progressDialog == null || !progressDialog.isShowing())
                        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(staticThis, "", "Querying...");
...
});
```

The app crashes and I get "Activity has leaked window" error.

I have this method at the end of my Activity but it doesn't seem to help:

```
public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if(progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

Have you got any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show from where are you calling `ProgressDialog.show` ?

Comment: @ShobhitPuri I edited my question with the full code of the call provided